# What are the chances that these programs are viruses

Tags: windows-7, virus

In Windows Task Manager I see four programs that don't have descriptions. csrss.exe, winlogon.exe, atieclxx.exe, and nvvsvc.exe. If I right click on them and select "Open File Location" nothing happens. Is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

csrss.exe and winlogon.exe are windows core processes. atieeclxx.exe is for you ATI or AMD card drivers I believe. nvvsvn.exe is probably "NVIDIA Driver Helper Service"

Comment: Isn't it abnormal that these files can't be found by the process manager?

Comment: That's because you don't run it as an administrator.